# Target first li element with div class on page Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jQuery I am trying to target the first `li` element on a page within a specific div> I am also getting the length (count) of it. The code I have so far does not work? Any ideas?

```
var Count = $(item).find('.item-colours ul li').first.length;
```

Comment: `first` is a method not a property, so it's `.first()`, not `.first`. Other than that we can't debug this without seeing the HTML, as it's a DOM traversal issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to get the `length` of a jQuery collection of only one element?

Comment: @DavidThomas I did have the same thought, presumably they are doing it to check if the element exists, although that makes `first()` redundant

Comment: @Rory: yeah, that occurred to me after I'd posted the comment, but I thought I'd leave it there just to clarify; mainly because of OP wants to test the length - to check for existence - then he should be caching the collection, otherwise there's the initial selection to check if it exists followed by another selection to retrieve the right element (which is fine, and it works, but it just feels sloppy).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the "first" part already in the query:

```
$(item).find('.item-colours ul li:first-of-type')
```